# Get random facebook UID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get an existing random facebook uid without generating random numbers and polling `https://graph.facebook.com/[RANDOM_NUMBER]` to check if a user exists?

Comment: Check some of your friends ids and select a range between different ids that are closed by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Facebook sure as hell didn't make a feature like that. That would void privacy policies.

The whole idea of a user id, is that it's a unique incremented number in the database. The unique ID's would only get bigger from there.
So, for example, your range could be from 1000000 - 1200000 so you poll those two boundaries to make sure they both exist. IF they do, you get the random # from there.

Of course, if Facebook removes the entire row in the db when users delete their accounts, then there will be holes in that range of numbers.

Comment: Facebook user IDs are not sequential, though they were at one point - so sequentially checking will not work apart from the first few million users

Comment: Well, I guess their progression algorithm would answer your question then.